# Uncaught TypeError: slider.slides.on is not a function

Tags: flexslider

I am using flexSlider in my website.I am using Slider with Carousel Slider as Navigation .It is not working,It is giving error

"Uncaught TypeError: slider.slides.on is not a function"

in the console of my browser.I don't know how to solve this problem?

Here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
// The slider being synced must be initialized first
$('#carousel').flexslider({
animation: "slide",
controlNav: false,
animationLoop: false,
slideshow: false,
itemWidth: 210,
itemMargin: 5,
asNavFor: '#slider'
});

$('#slider').flexslider({
animation: "slide",
controlNav: false,
animationLoop: false,
slideshow: false,
sync: "#carousel"
});
});
</script>
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<li>
  <img src="back1.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="back2.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="back3.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="back4.jpg" />
</li>
<!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
</ul>
</div>
<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<li>
  <img src="back1.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="back2.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="back3.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="back4.jpg" />
</li>
<!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
</ul>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.drupal.org/node/2401623      =>   I ran into this same error. It turns out that the latest Flexslider library requires jQuery 1.7+. Installing the jQuery Update module resolved the issue for me.